# Excel VBA SUMIF Super slow code

Tags: excel, vba

I have SUMIF running really really slow. My data has 14,800 Rows and 39 Columns.

I do the following:

```
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Application.DisplayStatusBar = False

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.EnableEvents = False

ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
```

**EDITED TO ADD more potentially relevant code that may be interacting with the SUMIF command**

It may be relevant to the speed issue so I'll mention it. I get the user to open a file from wherever they may have stored the report. The file then stays open. Maybe that is a problem. I don't know if it should be some other way.. like I close it but keep the address in mind or something??

```
    FilterType = "Text Files (*.txt),*.txt," & "Comma Separated Files (*.csv),*.csv," & "ASCII Files (*.asc),*.asc," & "All Files (*.*),*.*"

        FilterIndex = 4

        Title = "File to be Selected"

        File_path = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:=FilterType, FilterIndex:=FilterIndex, Title:=Title)

            If File_path = "" Then

                MsgBox "No file was selected."

            Exit Sub

            End If



        Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(File_path)
        Original_Name = ActiveWorkbook.Name
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
            ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
        End If



     Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws1 = wb1.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws1

    FinalColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    FinalRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row



    For j = 1 To FinalColumn
                        If .Cells(1, j).Value = "Effec.Date" Then
                                Effective_Date_Column = j
                        ElseIf .Cells(1, j).Value = "FolderId" Then
                                FolderId_column = j
                        ElseIf .Cells(1, j).Value = "FolderNotional" Then
                                 FolderNotional_column = j

                        End If
         Next j 




    'range_Total_Folder_Fixed = .Cells(2, Total_Folder_Column).Address & ":" & .Cells(FinalRow, Total_Folder_Column).Address

    range_FolderId_Fixed = .Cells(2, FolderId_column).Address & ":" & .Cells(FinalRow, FolderId_column).Address
     range_FolderId_Cell = .Cells(2, FolderId_column).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)

    range_FolderNotional_Fixed = .Cells(2, FolderNotional_column).Address & ":" & .Cells(FinalRow, FolderNotional_column).Address
```

Everything runs in 8-10 seconds until we come to the lie below. Now the total time jumps to a 150 seconds.

```
  .Range(range_Total_Folder_Fixed).Formula = "=SUMIF(" & range_FolderId_Fixed & "," & range_FolderId_Cell & "," & range_FolderNotional_Fixed & ")"
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better (more efficient) way to write a general formula?

**EDIT: Code generated Raw Formula**

Some of the excel worksheet functions in my code:

```
     .Range(range_Isnumber).Formula = "=(RIGHT(" & range_TradeId_cell & ",2)<> ""IB"")*1"
     .Range(range_Is_IB).Formula = "=(RIGHT(" & range_TradeId_cell & ",2)= ""IB"")*1"

     .Range(range_Exceptions).Formula = "=(SUMIF(" & range_FolderId_Fixed & "," & range_FolderId_Cell & "," & range_Isnumber_fixed & ")= COUNTIF(" & range_FolderId_Fixed & "," & range_FolderId_Cell & "))*1+(SUMIF(" & range_FolderId_Fixed & "," & range_FolderId_Cell & "," & range_Is_IB_fixed & ")= COUNTIF(" & range_FolderId_Fixed & "," & range_FolderId_Cell & "))*1  "
  .Range("C13").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH([SCL_FL_2013_11_30.xlsx]Rest!R2C2:R2321C2,[SCL_FL_2013_11_30.xlsx]Rest!R2C2:R2321C2,0),MATCH([SCL_FL_2013_11_30.xlsx]Rest!R2C2:R2321C2,[SCL_FL_2013_11_30.xlsx]Rest!R2C2:R2321C2,0))>0,1))"
```

So Stuff like

```
 Range("I2")=SUMIF($H$2:$H$5,H2,$G$2:$G$5)
```

Where the data could be like

```
RowG   RowH   RowI

Alice   1      4

Alice    3     4 

Bob      9     17

Bob     8      17

Dan      2      2
```

**EDIT2 : Implementing Sam's solution, I am getting errors:**

```
   Set range_FolderId_Fixed = .Range(.Cells(2, FolderId_column), .Cells(FinalRow, FolderId_column))
   Set range_FolderId_Cell = .Range(.Cells(2, FolderId_column),.Cells(FinalRow, FolderId_column))
   Set range_FolderNotional_Fixed = .Range(.Cells(2, FolderNotional_column), .Cells(FinalRow, FolderNotional_column))
   Set range_Total_Folder_Fixed = .Range(.Cells(2, Total_Folder_Column), .Cells(FinalRow, Total_Folder_Column))

   .Range(range_Total_Folder_Fixed).Value = SumIf_func(range_FolderId_Fixed, range_FolderId_Cell, range_FolderNotional_Fixed)
```

I am getting a type application defined or object defined  error in the line below.

```
   .Range(range_Total_Folder_Fixed).Value = SumIf_func(range_FolderId_Fixed, range_FolderId_Cell, range_FolderNotional_Fixed)
```

I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: Do you [change calculation mode](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/optimize.htm) to manual at all in your macro? That may help speed it up.

Comment: @Sam Thanks. Yes, I do have it in manual in the beginning of the code
.

Comment: Do you need the CountIf funtions in the sheet? or would you be happy if the macro just entered the result of the function into the range?

Comment: @Sam oh.. good point. I guess I would be happy with just the values. The input file is generated somewhere else and I don't expect to change any values outside of the macro. So I can remove ".Formula" and replace it with ".Value" ? ACtually can you please write the syntax for it becasue I am getting a lot of errors, type mismatch etc

Comment: Unfortunately not quite that simple, but doing the calculation within memory and outputting the values would be a lot lot faster.. I'll see have a go and see if I can come up with a suitable answer for you ;)

Comment: Can you add 2 or 3 of the raw formulas that your code generates to your question please.

Comment: @Sam I don't know what a Raw formula is? or what "generates Raw Formuala" means. I'll put my best guess/interpretation in the questions.

Comment: what does `range_Total_Folder_Fixed` evaluate to? the code doesn't seem slow at all. There must be something else slowing it down from my pov.

Comment: @mehow range_Total_Folder_Fixed from debug.Print was $AI$2:$AI$14741 I can tell you the other three as well.

Comment: this is the potential cause. You are filling 14739 cells with a formula. Do you really need to keep the formula in a cell? How about evaluating the formula and inserting results only?

Comment: range_FolderId_fixed is $B$2:$B$14741
range_FolderId_cell is B2
range_ FolderNotional_Fixed is $L$2:$L$14741

Comment: @mehow ok so like Sam said, I need to use values. Ok thanks. Can you tell me how to do that. Whatever I have tried is giving me errors. btw I will be away from my comp for 4-5 hours so I'll respond when I come back. Thanks

Comment: `.Range(range_Total_Folder_Fixed).Value = ` should be `range_Total_Folder_Fixed.Value = `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok this is what I came up with

```
 Public Function SumIf_func(rng As Range, _
                            criteria As Range, _
                            sumRange As Range) As Variant()

Dim rngArr() As Variant
Dim sumArr() As Variant
Dim criteriaArr() As Variant
Dim returnArr() As Variant

Dim temp As Double

rngArr = rng.Value2
sumArr = sumRange.Value2
criteriaArr = criteria.Value2

If UBound(sumArr) <> UBound(rngArr) Then _
Err.Raise 12345, "SumIf_func", "Sum range and check range should be the same size"

If UBound(sumArr, 2) <> 1 Or UBound(rngArr, 2) <> 1 Then _
Err.Raise 12346, "SumIf_func", "Sum range and check range should be a single column"

ReDim returnArr(1 To UBound(criteriaArr), 1 To 1)

    For c = LBound(criteriaArr) To UBound(criteriaArr)

            returnArr(c, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(rng, criteriaArr(c, 1), sumRange)                
    Next c

SumIf_func = returnArr

End Function
```

---

This function takes in three ranges:

- The range to check
- The range where the criteria are
- The range where the values to sum are

The range to check and the sum range should both be the same length and only be 1 column across.

The array that is returned will be the same size as the criteria array..

Here is an example of usage:

```
Public Sub test_SumIf()

Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheet1

Dim rng As Range, sumRng As Range, criteria As Range

Set rng = ws.Range("A1:A100")
Set sumRng = ws.Range("B1:B100")
Set criteria = ws.Range("C1:C10")

ws.Range("D1:D10").Value = SumIf_func(rng, criteria, sumRng)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is interesting that we have to manually get it to loop. I am probably using 6 or 7 Excel Functions at this point, so I will have to re-create each of those functions so I can get em to loop over the range that I want em to. hmm..

Comment: It was quite quick when I tested it. 16000 rows in each range took less than 6 seconds to complete. If the `SumIf` is the bottle neck in your code, then why do you have to re-create the other functions?

Comment: I was sequentially testing my code for bottlenecks and this SumIf came up in the first 5% of the code. I haven't gotten to the rest of the code yet but I am guessing that all of the other occasions when I am using formula, things would slow down in a similar fashion. They may be other stuff too.

Comment: Yeah.. You're probably right. Also, your sheet will be more usable if you exclude the functions and the file size will be smaller..

Comment: btw my variables  range_FolderId_Fixed = .Cells(2, FolderId_column).Address & ":" & .Cells(FinalRow, FolderId_column).Address are strings so now I have to convert your function to input strings or change my range expressions into range type. While I try to figure that out, any tip/suggestion would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Convert them to ranges... That should be quite simple `.Range(.Cells(2, FolderId_column), .Cells(FinalRow, FolderId_column))`

Comment: How do I get some of the ranges to have $ and some not to have. I want ws.Range("D1:D10").Value = SumIf_func($A$1:$A$10, A1, $B$1:$B$10). As I am trying to implement your code, I am getting some object errors and some type mismatch error inside the private function. I have to step out for an hour, I will update the question when I come back with a clear description of what I am trying and what the errors are. Thanks.

Comment: Let the function do the work and just pass in a range containing all the criteria... Look at the usage example.

Comment: I've tried to implement your method, but it's not working. Can you take a look at the bottom part of the main question please.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42754/discussion-between-sam-and-amatya)